# Setting up WSO2 products on a single machine

Tags: soa, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have been trying to start WSO2 ESB and WSO2 DSS on my machine. I am currently having port conflicts. How do i resolve this.?

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the port by changing the offset in

`WSO2DSS_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml`

```
<Offset>1</Offset>
```

default value is 0 and port is 9443, change it to 1, then DSS will start in 9444 port.

More info [DSS](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Glossary#Glossary-Portoffset), [ESB](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Glossary#Glossary-Portoffset)

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the offset parameter every time you run a server, like this:

```
./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=1
```